# Events sometimes fail to fire in Angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser

I have an Angular front-end with a PHP/MySQL backend. The application runs reliably at a number of client installations, both wired and wireless, cable and DSL, Chrome and Firefox. One user, however, can use the app for anywhere from 3-4 to 20 minutes or more, then some browser events stop firing - usually ng-blur and/or ng-change.

I've looked through the code repeatedly, to no avail. All the other users are fine. This user has attempted the app on 2 different Dell laptops using Win7 and Chrome, both wired and wireless, and experiences a similar issue each time.

Can anyone suggest a reason for this erratic behavior, like browser add-ins or network security programs that interfere with browser operation?

Comment: The times I've seen this happen have been because the code throws an error that causes a cascade of other errors. So the first place to check would be the error console on the clients machine. Are you able to post some code in your question that replicates the issues you are seeing? Without it the answers are  just speculation.

Comment: Problem clarified. See answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have located the problem. After checking with my users, I found that the one experiencing the problem was using AVG antivirus, all the rest were using McAfee or Norton.
I installed AVG on an older machine, and within a couple of minutes was seeing the same sort of problems. I'm considering this "solved".